# Mantine Radio button displays incorrectly

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, mantine

I'm using `Mantine v7.0.0` with `Next.js v13.5.2` and `Tailwind v3.3.3`.
When I create `<Radio />` elements the `svg` of element is being displayed separately from radio button instead of replacing it. Which results in such behaviour:

[image]

Neither of black circles is clickable and adding/removing `<RadioGroup>` has no result.
My component is:

```
import { MantineProvider, Radio, RadioGroup} from "@mantine/core";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <MantineProvider>
      <RadioGroup className={"flex"}>
        <Radio name={"123"} value={"email"} label={"Email"} />
        <Radio name={"123"} value={"phone"} label={"Phone"} />
      </RadioGroup>
    </MantineProvider>
  )
}
```

And my `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "nextjstest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "run": "npm run dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mantine/carousel": "^7.0.0",
    "@mantine/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@mantine/dates": "^7.0.0",
    "@mantine/form": "^7.0.0",
    "@mantine/hooks": "^7.0.0",
    "@mantine/next": "^6.0.21",
    "@types/node": "20.6.4",
    "@types/react": "18.2.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.16",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "eslint": "8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.2",
    "next": "13.5.2",
    "postcss": "8.4.30",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
}
```

Another thing to note: removing `display:flex` results in svg's being too ginormous to even fully display on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately some Tailwind.css styles overrides some of Mantine components styles. Just remove import of tailwind base from globals.css

More details [here](https://github.com/orgs/mantinedev/discussions/1672) from github discussion.